# HTML option tag with PHP MYSQL SELECT query causing everything after the tag to not display

Tags: php, html, pdo

I am creating a traditional insert php page with PDO to MySQL. However, I get a problem where the rest of the insert page did not display everything after HTML option tag as seen on screenshot 1.

Then I decided to grab the snippet of the option tag to new file and it did show the content as seen on screenshot 2.

Here is Screenshot 1: 
[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

This is the troubled snippet:

```
<td>
    <select>
        <?php
        include_once 'connect.php';

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM kota";
        $query2 = $conn->query($sql2);

        while ($row = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['nama']."</option>";
        }

        $conn = null;
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Full code snippet: https://pastebin.com/00GQE2i6

Is there anything I got it wrong? Or should I split the page into an html and php file? Any suggestion?

Comment: _Small Point_ You should only be connecting ONCE per script. The connect process is quite slow

Comment: Are you doing any error checking? Did you set EXCEPTION mode in the connection?

Comment: Quite possibly using `include_once 'connect.php';` for the SECOND time in the script is actually causing this problem, as it wont do the second one

Comment: _From the manual_ The include_once statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again, and include_once returns TRUE. As the name suggests, the file will be included just once.

Comment: Yes I did. It should throw an error if there's any problem. But it didn't.

Comment: See above 2 comments

Comment: Include the connection script ONCE and then remove all the `$conn = null;` PHP will close the connection for you at the end of the script

Comment: Removing the second include_once didn't resolve the issue though. I tried removing and re-adding it.

Comment: Thats because you did `$conn = null;` after using the connection for the first time thus destroying the connection!!!!!

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the help. You fixed it. It's always this nifty small things I get troubled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the manual:

> The include_once statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again, and include_once returns TRUE. As the name suggests, the file will be included just once.

So as you are using it twice, the second `include_once()` will do nothing. Now as you are doing a `$conn = null;` after each use of the connection you have destroyed the connection you made from the first `include_once()` so there is no connection remaining, and the second `include_once()` will not remake the connection as it will not be executed by PHP.

You should really only need to connect once per script. So leave the first `include_once()` where it is and remove the second.

Then look for all the `$conn = null;` lines in your code and remove all of them. PHP will automatically close a database connection when it cleans up memory after the script completes.